# Laravel Validation Rules

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My need is just Laravel validation Rules.I want to use Laravel validation to check variables. and show custom errors by returning string in controller.(I dont use view, blade, session,... I just return string)

```
if(strlen($username) < 4) return '{"r": "US","msg": "username is short"}';
if(strlen($username) > 64) return '{"r": "UL","msg": "username is long"}';
if(strlen($address) > 200) return '{"r": "A","msg": "wrong address"}';
```

**I want something like this:**

```
if($validation->username->min has error)
     return 'string:username is short';

if($validation->address->max has error)
     return 'string:address is long';

if($validation->username->unique has error)
     return 'string:username already exists';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation) of validation in Laravel. You don't have to handle every case manually. `Validator::make()` will generate a validator object for you. The first parameter will take your data as an associative array. The second argument will define all rules as desired. As a third, optional parameter you may define alternative error messages if you don't like the default ones. The will be returned in the `errors()` method in case something isn't valid.

```
$validator = Validator::make($yourDataArray, [
    'username' => 'min:4|max:64|exists:table,username',
    'address' => 'max:64'
], [
    'min' => ':attribute is too short.',
    'exists' => ':attribute already exists.
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return $validator->errors()->all();
}
```

If you don't want to get an array with all errors at once, you can get the state of each field like so:

```
if ($validator->errors()->has('username')) { // Username field is invalid
    return $validator->errors()->first('username'); // Get the first error
}
```

And if you want to know what rule exactly failed, you can use something like that:

```
if(isset($validator->failed()['username']['Max'])) {
    return 'Username is too long.';
}
```

Comment: I knew it. but I want something Like this: if ($validator->errors()->has('username')->has('max')) { // Username max field is invalid