# Inserting data to database laravel

Tags: php, laravel

At the moment I am working with Laravel. I am trying to insert data into a database. It is not user data, but product data. Costumers have to be able to insert a title, description and price of a product into the database.

I have looked at the laravel website, however, I was unable to find anything. There are some people with the same question as mine on StackOverflow. However, the answers that were given to them do not work for me.

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function insertform(){
        return view('home');
        } 
        public function insert(Request $request){
            $productname = $request->input('title');
            $description = $request->input('description');
            $price = $request->input('price');
            $data=array('title'=>$productname,"description"=>$description,"price"=>$price);
            DB::table('products')->insert($data);
            echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
            echo '<a href = "/insert">Click Here</a> to go back.';
}
}
```

My view:

```
@section('content')
<h1>Add your new items here:</h1>

<form method="get">
<div class="title">
  <div class="title">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="title">Title</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" aria-label="title" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="description">
  <div class="description">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="description">Description</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" aria-label="description" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="price">
  <div class="price">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="price">Price</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" aria-label="price" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
<br>
<br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Insert Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
@endsection
```

My web.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('insert','ProductsController@insertform');
Route::post('create','ProductsController@insert'); 

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

My database structure:

[image]

The home and welcome, along with some code in the web.php, has been made by authentication.

Hopefuly you guys can help me out. I want to make sure that the product data is inserted into the database.

Comment: Change your form method to `post` and specify action.

Comment: Please add your database structure in your question.

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev I changed it to post, it gives the following error: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: I meant that you defined `create` post method while the method of your form is `get`. Also specify `action` in your form: `action="/create"`

Comment: @leonardeveloper I added it.

Comment: I changed my action to /create. What else? It gives a page expired now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your web.php, Add route names

```
Route::get('insert','ProductsController@insertform')->name('product.create');
Route::post('create','ProductsController@insert')->name('product.store');
```

In your view, change method to post and add action attribute and csrf field.

```
<form  action="{{ route('product.store') }}" method="post">
@csrf
```

In Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function insertform(){
        return view('home');
    } 

    public function insert(Request $request){
        $productname = $request->input('title');
        $description = $request->input('description');
        $price = $request->input('price');
        $data = array(
            "title" => $productname,
            "description" => $description,
            "price" => $price
        );

        DB::table('products')->insert($data);

        echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
        echo '<a href = "/insert">Click Here</a> to go back.';
    }
}
```

Alternate you can directly add action without route name

```
<form  action="/create" method="post">
@csrf
```

Comment: it gives the following error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

Comment: add use DB before class declaration

Comment: thank you very much friend, almost done. I believe this is the last error; SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'title' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `products` (`title`, `description`, `price`) values (rsgjdyj, yrjdj, ryjjry))

Comment: Share products table columns.

Comment: what column should I add?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205871/discussion-between-masood-khan-and-johan-delft).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use DB class. Instead create a model called Product and use model function to create or update data into table.

> php artisan make:model Product

```
$product= Product::create([
    'name' =>  $request->name, # declared as fillable on Product model
    'description' => $request->description,
    ...
]);
```

Convert the route of /insert into POST and add csrf field in your form

```
@csrf
```

OR

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

On your controller validation of input in insert function.

Also take a look at these -

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models
2. [Laravel Validation Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199460/laravel-validation-rules)
   or https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Answer (score 0):

**In laravel 5.6 i can show you how to insert the data and display the data to the index page**

so first of all i can code my route 
in here we can use 2 routes

first is index page route
second is store and in store controller you can display your stored data.

```
Route::get('/FAQ_page', 'SettingController@FAQ_page')->name('FAQ_page');
Route::get('/FAQ_page/create', 'SettingController@FAQ_page_create')->name('FAQ_page.create');
Route::post('/FAQ_page/store', 'SettingController@FAQ_pagestore');
```

now make a database and connect to your module
this is your module

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FAQpage extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'p66_FAQ_page';
     public $timestamps = false;

      protected $primaryKey = 'fid';
}
```

now make your controller like this

```
public function FAQ_page()
    {   
        $data = FAQpage::get();
        return view('SuperAdmin.settings.FAQ_page', compact('data'));
    }

     public function FAQ_page_create()
    {

        return view('SuperAdmin.settings.FAQ_page_create');
    }

    public function FAQ_pagestore(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'FAQ_question'=> 'required',
            'FAQ_answer'=> 'required',
            'Sort_order'=> 'required|max:4',
            'FAQ_departments'=> 'required',
        ]);

        $data = new FAQpage();
        $data->FAQ_question = $request->get('FAQ_question');
        $data->FAQ_answer = $request->get('FAQ_answer');
        $data->Sort_order = $request->get('Sort_order');
        $data->FAQ_departments = $request->get('FAQ_departments');
        $data->Created_date = Carbon::now();
        $data->save();


        return redirect('/SuperAdmin/FAQ_page');
    }
```

thank you